# ExecuteScalar returning wrong value

Tags: c#, sql, database, executescalar

I have a little problem with selecting max ID from my database. This is my code:

```
string checkcat = "SELECT MAX(PRODUCT_ID) FROM CMS_PRODUKTY WHERE (CATEGORY_ID = CATEGORY_ID) AND (CLIENT_ID = @CLIENT_ID)";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(checkcat, con);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@CATEGORY_ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = kategoria;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@CLIENT_ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = HiddenField1.Value;
con.Open();
int noweid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
con.Close();
```

The point is the new int "noweid" should be 1 or higher - depend on product_id inside table, but it's returning 0. I don't have any idea why... The other variables - kategoria and HiddenField1.Value are correct.

Any ideas what did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried executing this query against the database using SQL Server Management Studio and verifying that it returns 1 or higher there?

Comment: It won't solve your problem but you have a typo `(CATEGORY_ID = CATEGORY_ID)` should be `(CATEGORY_ID = @CATEGORY_ID)` - note the `@`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
WHERE (CATEGORY_ID = CATEGORY_ID)
```

but you want

```
WHERE (CATEGORY_ID = @CATEGORY_ID)
```

You should also parse the string to `int`:

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@CLIENT_ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(HiddenField1.Value);
```

maybe `kategoria` is also a `string`, then parse it also to `int`.

Comment: Thanks. It's working perfectly. Have read this code thousand times and didn't see such a mistake... Just needed to add @ to sql condition.